# Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 13c - Email notification should send only once

Tags: oracle-enterprise-manager

I have an alert message with tablespace usage that should recheck the status in Cloud Control 13c and send the email only once, but it sends every 30 minutes. It shows me the TS_USAGE error of the tablespaces when it grows over 95%.

Can I have something configured to send only once when it happens and then some kind of clear notifications to send back that everything is ok, when I resize manually the tablespace and fix the issue?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the default setting (for repeated notifications). I guess you have a customized environment and someone configured repeated notifications on purpose.

Repeated notifications can be configured globally in `Setup` / `Notifications` / `Global Repeat settings`, or specifically for metric alerts in `Setup` / `Incidents` / `Incident Rules` / `"your rule set"` / `Rules` / `Create incident for critical metric alerts` / `Actions` / `Repeat Notifications`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But in the exising rules (that someone defined before me) I do not see in the actions repeat notifiations. Also when I edit the rules I cannot find it there. The global repeat settings are not-checked (disabled). Version is Cloud Control 13c.

Comment: Greetings. Thanks for the help. It workd with the changed rules. But I would also like to have a rule (maybe I can edit the existing one) to have an Email back when I solved the issue that alarm wrote (for an example tablespace extension...)